# How do I install Predis on XAMPP windows?

Tags: php, redis, installation, predis

I installed Predis on XAMPP windows machine using pearhub (pear install pearhub/predis). It installed without any error messages.
But when I do the following

```
<?php
require "Predis.php";
$redis = new Predis/Client();
$redis->set('library', 'predis');
$value = $redis->get('library');
?>
```

It says Predis class not found. Any ideas how to properly install this on windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install Redis first, and then Predis will work. Predis is only an interface for Redis.

Because you are on windows, you can find information in the executable here: https://github.com/dmajkic/redis/downloads

Also, I noticed in your code, you have this:

```
$redis = new Predis/Client();
```

It should be this:

```
$redis = new Predis_Client();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to start  **redis-server.exe** from **C:/redis** folder, then paste following code in your php file.

```
<?php 
    require "predis/autoloader.php";
    Predis\Autoloader::register();
    $redis = new Predis\Client();
    $redis = new Predis\Client(array(
      "scheme" => "tcp",
      "host" => "127.0.0.1",
      "port" => 6379));
    if($redis)
    {
         echo "Redis connected succesfully";
    }
    else
    {
         echo "Redis Not connected";
    }
?>
```

Comment: hey i am try Redis but got this error  `Class 'Predis\Autoloader' not found in C:\xampp-portable\htdocs\done\test.php on line 3`

Comment: require "predis/autoloader.php";
It would be 
    require "predis/autoload.php";

It solve my problem.